# ngOnChanges doesn't trigger changes

Tags: angular

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/0LHeJ3Fyz5gdjJqQ?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1
Here's a plunkr. It's just for example.

In real project i got something like

```
<input [(ngModel)]='_data.name' [name]='name' />
```

I pass some data for input by using ngOnInit lifehook
And i cant understand why my ngOnChanges hook doesn't trigger changes when i write something in my `<input>`

The `_data` takes data from json/server by using services http request, then i get `name` in my `<input>`, or something on
The question is: how to detect changes with ngOnChange lifehook in my situation
I try to set `[name]='name'` and then take it using `@Input` like that

```
@Input() name: string;
```

Then in ngOnChanges

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log(changes.name.currentValue);
}
```

Why i do not see anything in my console? Why ngOnChanges is not working this way? 
I need to take value from my input, then detect it changes using ngOnChanges 
No errors in console, no data, just nothing, empty

Comment: why are you want to use `ngOnChanges` ?, instead listen `onChange`, `input` or `keyup` events on your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the relation between two components is not well implemented.

We should have a deal firstly that `@input()` **[decorators are implementend only in a child component](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding)**, that means, you have to make your changes in the father component and pass those changes to the child so it will invoke its `ngOnChanges` method. That is to say:

in your Father component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <example [name]="name"></example> <!-- Here you intend to call your child -->
            <input [(ngModel)]="name"/>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class App {
    name: string;
    constructor() {
        this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
    }
}
```

And Remove that `<input [(ngModel)]="name"/>` from `Example` template.

***[A working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n3fk4v)***.

Answer (score 0):

`@input` is only to communicate with outer component not for own template. Instead you can use `ngModelChange`

```
import {Component, NgModule, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Input } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  template: `
   <input [(ngModel)]='name' (ngModelChange)="onChanges()" />
 `,
})

export class Example implements OnInit{
  private _value: string;
  name: string;

  // @Input() name: string; <--- no need

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = 'qwe';
  }

  onChanges() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }


}
```